# Titanium "resume" event not fired on unlock (iphone)

Tags: events, mobile, titanium, resume

I am currently working on an app that check for GPS data every X mins/seconds. I use the "pause" event to stop it while the app is in background and resume it with "resume" event. No problem there.

The problem is when you lock the device: it fires the pause event but won't resume on unlock. Is it a known bug? Is there another event I should know of?
Thanks!

Comment: What reason may one have not to use "resumed" instead of "resume" since the former seems to do all the latter does when resuming from background? The main reason asking relates to the fact that my app needs to run a counter while locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for the "resumed" (with a D at the end) event instead of "resume".

You will get "resumed" for app relaunch (along with the "resume" event), but also for unlock, dismiss of a notification, dismiss the multitasking bar, etc.